# How to test Stanford Sentiment model?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I know the following command can be used to train a Stanford sentiment model

```
java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz
```

Now I want to how to test the model with the testing dataset.
I tried using `-trainPath` option, it didn't seem to work. I didn't find anything neither on the official documentation nor on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `Evaluate` class.

```
java -Xmx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate -model <model> -treebank <treebank>
```

Comment: Should I put `train.txt` in place of `<treebank>`?

Comment: Whatever file you want to test on, in the same format as the train.txt or dev.txt from your original command